# Angular 4 Interceptor with ngx-restangular

Tags: angular, restangular

I'm using [ngx-restangular](http://ngx-restangular.com/) with Angular 4.

I want to intercept the requests and, if the http status code is 403, I want to redirect the user to the login page.

Now I have this code on my `app.module.ts`

```
/**
 * NGX-ANGULAR configs.
 */
// Function for setting the default restangular configuration
export function RestangularConfigFactory (RestangularProvider) {

  // Set base URL
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://192.168.1.79:8080/api/');

  // If token not valid/expired
  RestangularProvider.addErrorInterceptor((response, subject, responseHandler) => {

    if (response.status === 403) {

      // Redirect user to login page
      //Router.navigateByUrl(['login']);

      return false; // error handled
    }
    return true; // error not handled
  });
}
```

The `Router.navigateByUrl(['login']);` obviously is not working.

I've tried to import the `Router` from `@angular/router` and inject it on the AppModule constructor but then can't access the `this` inside `RestangularConfigFactory` function.

Anyone can help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I came across your question while trying to figure out the same thing, and thought I'd share my solution with you (and anyone else looking).

When you set up the `RestangularModule` module in your `imports`, you can specify any additional services you want to pass to the config factory. In my case, I was already passing my authentication service:

```
export function restangularConfigFactory(restangularProvider, auth) {
  // set base url and add token to all requests
  ...
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    RestangularModule.forRoot([AuthService], restangularConfigFactory)
  ],
  ...
})
```

So all I had to do was to add `Router` to my function parameters and my list of services, like this (don't forget to `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`):

```
export function restangularConfigFactory(restangularProvider, auth, router) {
  // set base url and add token to all requests
  ...
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    RestangularModule.forRoot([AuthService, Router], restangularConfigFactory)
  ],
  ...
})
```

And then I could use `router` like I do anywhere else:

```
export function restangularConfigFactory(restangularProvider, auth, router) {
  ...
  restangularProvider.addErrorInterceptor((response, subject, responseHandler) => {
    if (response.status == 403) {
      router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  });
  ...
}
```